# How to give multiple parameters to django's url in various patterns

Tags: python, django

I use Django 1.11.
I'm thinking about url design like this 
I want to use the part surrounded by `{}` as a parameter.

```
v1/
v1/{param1}
v1/{param1}/category/{param2}
v1/category/{param2}
```

I tried to make the url pattern as below

```
url(r'^v1/?$', some_view.SomeClass.as_view()),
url(r'^v1/(?P<param1>.*)/?', some_view.SomeClass.as_view()),
url(r'^v1/(?P<param1>.*)/category/(?P<param2>.*)/?', some_view.SomeClass.as_view()),
url(r'^v1/category/(?P<param2>.*)/?', some_view.SomeClass.as_view()),
```

After accessing `v1/param1/category/param2`.
Then `param1/category/param2` will come in the argument `{param1}` 
How do I get it done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're including `/` in your regex capture group. simply omit that

`(?P<param1>[^/]+)`